# What is the preferred way to use auto to declare a lambda variable in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Does anyone have any insight into the pros and cons of the various ways to use auto to declare a lambda variable?
For e.g.:

```
 auto Val = [] { };           // #1
 const auto &LVRef = [] { };  // #2
 auto &&RVRef = [] { };       // #3
```

Can anyone think of a compelling reason to not always prefer #1?

I imagine for a template function, the preferred way to declare a callable parameter is to use a universal reference?

```
template<class F> void foo(F&& f) { f(); }
```

Or do most guidelines prefer to declare it as a non-reference parameter?

```
template<class F> void foo(F f) { f(); }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Passing by reference vs by copy has significant implications for stateful functors.  Use whichever one has the behavior you desire.

Comment: `(F&&f){std::forward<F>(f)();}`, as if the functor has `()&&` overload and it was passed in as an rvalue, we do not want to waste it.  (note: nobody has a `()&&` overload).

Comment: @Yakk What do you mean "nobody has a `()&&` overload"?

Comment: @iavr I mean that I have yet to meet a functor with `operator()&&` overriden.  And lambdas and `std::function` do not have it overridden.  It would be interesting to add that to the standard... but sort of a chicken and microoptimization egg issue.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/tuple/fun/meta_tup.hpp) is one you can meet :-) For functors that carry state it makes sense to define 3 overloads for `&&`, `&`, `const&`, and I do this systematically. I hope there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @BenVoigt: ... which means pass by value, the caller can always opt to wrap the functor with 'std::ref'

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone think of a compelling reason to not always prefer #1?

No. #1 is simpler and there's no performance penalty vs. the other options.

Algorithms taking functors just take them by value normally, but using universal references is reasonable if you want to guarantee no copying the functor for some reason. If you're writing something that simply forwards the functor then use universal references.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually say #2, because I prefer differenting non-mutable and non-reference variables/functor, then declare every other variable `const auto&`. The reason I prefer to also use a reference is that you dont have to care if a function returns a generated value or a reference.